# MediaWiki: It's not possible to create user account using LDAP Authentication extension

Tags: active-directory, ldap, mediawiki, account

Not all users in LDAP are authorized to own an user account in my MediaWiki. I already have users logging in because I created their accounts before installing LDAP Plugin. Now, I need to create accounts for new employees and I always receive the message "Username entered already in use. Please choose a different name.", through Special:CreateAccount.

Obviously, If I disable all LDAP configuration in LocalSettings, I'm able to create a local user account with the same LDAP username. Then , if I enable LDAP configuration again, the user is recognized with LDAP password and he can log in. The fact is that I don't want to edit LocalSettings every time I have a new employee.

MediaWiki: 1.29.1

PHP: 5.5.21 (apache2handler)

PostgreSQL: 9LDAP

My configuration is below. Thanks in advance.

require_once ('.../extensions/LdapAuthentication/LdapAuthentication.php');

$wgAuth = new LdapAuthenticationPlugin();

$wgLDAPDomainNames = array( 'AD' );

$wgLDAPServerNames = array( 'AD' => 'url' );

$wgLDAPUseLocal = false;

$wgLDAPEncryptionType = array( 'AD' => 'clear' );

$wgLDAPPort = array( 'AD' => 389 );

$wgLDAPProxyAgent = array( 'AD' => 'CN=a,OU=b,DC=c,DC=d' );

$wgLDAPProxyAgentPassword = array( 'UFPE-AD' => 'password' );

$wgLDAPSearchAttributes = array( 'AD' => 'description' );

$wgLDAPBaseDNs = array( 'AD' => 'DC=c,DC=d' );

$wgLDAPDisableAutoCreate = array( 'AD' => true );

$wgLDAPPreferences = array( 'AD' => array( 'email' => 'mail', 'realname' => 'cn','nickname' => 'givenname') );

$wgLDAPLowerCaseUsername = array( 'AD' => true);

$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;

Comment: LdapAuthentication is unmaintained. You can find some info on replacement plans [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/LDAP_hub).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.